# Using TypeScript to write file or to device event log

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, typescript

I have a Windows Store application, which I wrote in TypeScript. What are the ways for me to read/write files in the device File System or in device Event Log in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu cannot get arbitrary file system access as you are sandboxed in windows store apps for user safety.

To get access to your storage look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx

Every JavaScript api applies to TypeScript.